# SQL query INSERT if NOT EXISTS with form params

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm having an issue figuring out how to only add entries to my database if it's not already there. I found the NOT EXISTS method but It's not working.

```
restaurantsModel.create = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("from restaurants.Model", req.body);
    db
        .manyOrNone(
            "INSERT INTO restaurants (res_id, name, city, image) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING * WHERE NOT EXISTS;",
            [
                req.body.restaurant_id,
                req.body.restaurant_name,
                req.body.restaurant_city,
                req.body.restaurant_image
            ]
        )
        .then(da
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT US?!?!

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: @rory.ap It's supposed to be written in caps.

Comment: @RobertColumbia it shows an error, if I remove the WHERE NOT EXISTS from the query, it will add the entry but if it already exists, it returns a JSON error on the browser.

Comment: @jenlearnsdev -- no, it's not.  Caps means you're yelling at us.  Here, I'll correct it for you.

Comment: Also, it's really terrible title.  It makes literally no sense.  This is a very poor quality question.  I suggest you give [ask] a thorough review before doing anything else here.

Answer (score 1):

Typically for something like this you would want to add a UNIQUE constraint to the actual DB table so that your code would just receive an error if it tried to insert a duplicate row. Then you can handle the error and return a message to the user.

However, you can use an INSERT statement that will check for the existence of a record with the desired values before performing the insert.

```
INSERT INTO Restaurants (res_id, name, city, image)
SELECT DISTINCT $1, $2, "$3, $4
FROM Restaurants
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Restaurants WHERE res_id = $1 AND name = $2 
    AND city = $3 AND image = $4)
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this approach because you would want the application to notify the user that a duplicate row existed rather than silently not inserting a row.

The other reason you might want to do this is because it will take longer to execute than running a simple query before the insert statement to check for duplicates, or using a db constraint.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I already had a UNIQUE constraint, I just needed to specify what to do if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax in your SQL:

```
if not exists **your condition**
begin
INSERT INTO restaurants (res_id, name, city, image) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
end
```